# Windows 10 Home disable gestures in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, fullscreen, tablet

How can I prevent end users from closing/switching .NET fullscreen application that is running on Windows 10 Home tablet please? The left swipe and right swipe gestures are still present allowing user to switch (or even close) that aplication. I would like to prevent users from existing that fullscreen app. It is W10 Home thus *Assigned Acces*s is not available there.
Thank you.
Slavek

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by trying to do the exact opposite.
Kill explorer.exe and you will not have gestures anymore.